# PDF External Signature - Trouble Hashing Document

Tags: pdf, hash, itext, digital-signature

First things first, I'm somewhat new to posting on StackOverflow, so please do tell me if I'm not providing enough information or something.

I'm interfacing with an external digital signature service. I can get a signature and add it to the original PDF using iTextSharp. It's correctly picked up by Adobe Acrobat; however, the signature is invalid because "The document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed".

I've managed to track the problem down to how I'm generating the original document's hash - as I understand it, the document's hash should be constant (ie. calls to the hashing function with the same document should always return the same hash) because said document hash is used to validate the signature. My hashing function, however, returns a different hash each time. Am I wrong in my assumption that this is a problem? If not, how would I make it have the desired behaviour?

Here goes my code:

```
public static string Hash(byte[] pdf, List<X509Certificate> chain, string hashAlgorithm, RCSignatureFieldsRecord fields, RCSignaturePositionRecord position)
{
        IDigest messageDigest = DigestAlgorithms.GetMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm);
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = BuildAppearence(pdf, chain, fields, position);

        Stream data = sap.GetRangeStream();
        byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, messageDigest);
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, false);
        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        byte[] signedAttributesHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(new MemoryStream(sh), messageDigest);

        IDigest digest = DigestUtilities.GetDigest(hashAlgorithm);
        byte[] messageHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(digest, signedAttributesHash);
        byte[] sha256Prefix = { 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20 };
        byte[] digestInfo = new byte[sha256Prefix.Length + messageHash.Length];
        sha256Prefix.CopyTo(digestInfo, 0);
        messageHash.CopyTo(digestInfo, sha256Prefix.Length);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(digestInfo);
}

private static PdfSignatureAppearance BuildAppearence(byte[] pdf, List<X509Certificate> chain, RCSignatureFieldsRecord fields, RCSignaturePositionRecord position)
{
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, baos, '\0', null, true);
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        sap.Certificate = chain[0];
        sap.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
        PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        dic.Date = new PdfDate(sap.SignDate);
        dic.Name = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(chain[0]).GetField("CN");

        
        sap.CryptoDictionary = dic;
        sap.Certificate = chain[0];
        sap.Acro6Layers = true;
        setupSignatureFields(sap, fields);
        setupVisualSignature(sap, position);

        Dictionary<PdfName, int> exc = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
        exc.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, 8192 * 2 + 2);
        sap.PreClose(exc);

        return sap;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Edit

Based on mkl's response, I've refactored my code. I've opted for the second option (closing `sap` with an empty signature and keeping `baos` with the half-signed PDF). However, I'm getting a (not very descriptive) exception when calling `sap.Close(dic)`:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.
> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
> at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.Close(PdfDictionary update)

Here's the updated code:

```cs
public static Tuple<string, byte[]> Hash(byte[] pdf, List<X509Certificate> chain, string hashAlgorithm, RCSignatureFieldsRecord fields, RCSignaturePositionRecord position)
{
        // build signature appearence
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, baos, '\0', null, true);
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        sap.Certificate = chain[0];
        sap.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
        PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        dic.Date = new PdfDate(sap.SignDate);
        dic.Name = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(chain[0]).GetField("CN");

        sap.CryptoDictionary = dic;
        sap.Certificate = chain[0];
        sap.Acro6Layers = true;
        setupSignatureFields(sap, fields);
        setupVisualSignature(sap, position);

        Dictionary<PdfName, int> exc = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
        exc.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, 8192 * 2 + 2);
        sap.PreClose(exc);

        // calculate hash
        IDigest messageDigest = DigestAlgorithms.GetMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm);
        Stream data = sap.GetRangeStream();
        byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, messageDigest);
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, false);
        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        byte[] signedAttributesHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(new MemoryStream(sh), messageDigest);

        IDigest digest = DigestUtilities.GetDigest(hashAlgorithm);
        byte[] messageHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(digest, signedAttributesHash);
        byte[] sha256Prefix = { 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20 };
        byte[] digestInfo = new byte[sha256Prefix.Length + messageHash.Length];
        sha256Prefix.CopyTo(digestInfo, 0);
        messageHash.CopyTo(digestInfo, sha256Prefix.Length);
        
        // close the signature appearence with an empty signature and return the hash and pdf with empty signature field
        sap.Close(dic); // throws an exception
        return new Tuple<string, byte[]>(Convert.ToBase64String(digestInfo), baos.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> as I understand it, the document's hash should be constant (ie. calls to the hashing function with the same document should always return the same hash) because said document hash is used to validate the signature. My hashing function, however, returns a different hash each time. Am I wrong in my assumption that this is a problem?

You are correctly assuming that the hash of a fixed document is constant. This after all is a major point of hashing.

You err, though, assuming that your use case is an example of this. Because you hash different documents in each run.

In `BuildAppearence` each time a different PDF is generated because in particular the current time is stored in it both as signing time (explicitly by your code) and as document modification time (implicitly by iText). Furthermore, a unique ID is generated and stored in the PDF (implicitly by iText). Depending on other aspects of the PDF there may yet be more entries in the PDF which change from call to call.

While it is possible to patch those implicitly set PDF entries in iText to become injectable, the clean way to implement signing would be to follow the iText signing examples and keep the originally produced version of the PDF and later inject the signature into it.

Comment: By "originally produced version of the PDF", I assume you mean sap specifically; as in I should save the `PdfSignatureAppearence` I create in `BuildAppearence` and reuse it in my `Sign` method, rather than calling `BuildAppearence` again. Is that correct? If not, could you please clarify how exactly I get the generated PDF?

Comment: Actually you have a choice. Either you indeed keep the `PdfSignatureAppearance` (and also the `MemoryStream baos`), inject the signature container using `PdfSignatureAppearance.Close`, and get the final PDF from `baos`. Or you immediately `Close` the signature appearance with an empty signature, keep the half-signed PDF in `baos`, and use `MakeSignature.SignDeferred` to eventually replace the empty signature with the actual one.

Comment: I updated the question with the second option, however I get an exception. Could you once again point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You have to *`Close` the signature appearance **with an empty signature***, i.e. you have to add a `PdfName.CONTENTS` entry to `dic` before calling `Close(dic)`. The value should to be a hex string filled with 0s to the full exclusion size.

Comment: I actually figured out what I was missing before your answer, which led me to a problem when replacing it with the actual signature. When I call `MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, "sigName", baos, sig)` I get an exception `No field`.
Should `"sigName"` instead be `sap.FieldName`?  If so, is there a way to set `sap.FieldName`?

Comment: I tested with passing `sap.FieldName` into `MakeSignature.SignDeferred` and it seems that is not the correct field (still raises a `No field` exception). I also tried using the same fieldName as in `sap.SetVisibleSignature` but got the same result.

Comment: *"I also tried using the same fieldName as in sap.SetVisibleSignature but got the same result."* - That should be the correct name, though.